# hibernate validation with annotation

Tags: hibernate, servlets

i just discover that my hibernate validations are not working. i am using hibernate3 with annotation. Please check following code.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "registration")
public class Pojo implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @NotNull
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "name", length=5)
    @NotNull
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "surname", length=5)
    @NotNull
    private String surname;
    @Column(name = "address", length=5)
    @NotNull
    private String address;
getters and setters

}
```

following is my servlet

```
System.out.println("Kshitij-----");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        Pojo r = new Pojo();
        r.setId(Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("id")));
        r.setName(request.getParameter("name"));
        r.setSurname(request.getParameter("surname"));
        r.setAddress(request.getParameter("address"));
        session.save(r);
        transaction.commit();
        session.close();
        out.println("Success.....");
```

It is inserting records without values. Should i add something new.?

Comment: I suggest to check that classpath contains `hibernate-validator` jar.

Comment: i am working on netbeans and it is providing all jars for hibernate. but i checked there and there was not hibernate-validator so i putted there and run project. Same thing. it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Validation is not the problem why are your data not saved. `session.close();` closes the session but you need to call flush before that. This is the corect order to work with session to succesfuly save your data:

```
flush the session
commit the transaction
close the session
handle exceptions
```

[See](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#flush%28%29) the docs

Comment: i am saying that i used validation through this annotations. and when i am submitting form without value so it has to give me validation error and that it is not giving. and storing blank space in database(not null). and that's why i used length. but it is not working.

Comment: All right I didnt quite understand your question... Well I dons see that you would implement any validation logic therefore you cant expect your entities to be validated. You should use event based validation or application validation... have a look at this article http://docs.huihoo.com/hibernate/annotations-reference-3.2.1/validator.html

Comment: So it means just these annotation are not enough to validate entity i have to extends Validator class.

Comment: You need to tell your application where and how to validate. Have a look at the chapter 4.2.2. Hibernate event-based validation and there you can see that you can validate your entities before insert and update. Or do it somewhere in your application...

Answer (score 0):

Try validating the entity directly with;

```
ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.byDefaultProvider().configure().traversableResolver(new CustomTraversableResolver() ).buildValidatorFactory();
Validator validator = factory.getValidator();
Set<ConstraintViolation<BaseValidationObject>> constraintViolations = Validator.validate(r);
```

and adding e.g. @Min(1) or @Length(1, 255) to your property annotations.

The constraintViolations variable will contain any failed conditions.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can try to drop your current table and recreate it after you add these constraints. Try some restart as well. I have the same problem before and it works. Not sure if this is your situation.